# Issue with BingX Swap Api Python HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, api, post, get, urllib

I'm using urllib.request.
I'm trying to use the BingX Swap Api with Python and I'm getting this error:
I'm trying to use the BingX Swap Api with Python and I'm getting this error:
I'm trying to use the BingX Swap Api with Python and I'm getting this error:
I'm trying to use the BingX Swap Api with Python and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Desktop\MyBot\MyApi.py", line 118, in <module>
main()
File "Desktop\MyBot\MyApi.py", line 103, in main
print("getLatestPrice:", getLatestPrice())
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Desktop\MyBot\MyApi.py", line 70, in getLatestPrice
return post(url, paramsStr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Desktop\MyBot\MyApi.py", line 19, in post
return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think that my code is ok.

This is My Code:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64
import hmac
import time

APIURL = "https://api-swap-rest.bingbon.pro"
APIKEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
SECRETKEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

def genSignature(path, method, paramsMap):
    sortedKeys = sorted(paramsMap)
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (x, paramsMap[x]) for x in sortedKeys])
    paramsStr = method + path + paramsStr
    return hmac.new(SECRETKEY.encode("utf-8"), paramsStr.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()

def post(url, body):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=body.encode("utf-8"), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

def getLatestPrice():
    paramsMap = {
        "symbol": "BTC-USDT",
    }
    sortedKeys = sorted(paramsMap)
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (x, paramsMap[x]) for x in sortedKeys])
    paramsStr += "&sign=" + urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(genSignature("/api/v1/market/getLatestPrice", "GET", paramsMap)))
    url = "%s/api/v1/market/getLatestPrice" % APIURL
    return post(url, paramsStr)



def main():
     print("getLatestPrice:", getLatestPrice())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```